# No Link to source-code in Chrome Devtools for React components

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools, performance-testing, create-react-app, source-maps

I use **create-react-app 16**.["react": "^16.8.4", "react-scripts": "^2.1.8"] 
I read the blog on profiling react performance by **Ben Schwarz** using **Chrome Dev tools**:
https://building.calibreapp.com/debugging-react-performance-with-react-16-and-chrome-devtools-c90698a522ad
He recommends to export your JS with **source-maps**.
When he does a **performance trace**, and clicks on a given react component in the User Timing section, specific component information shows in the Bottum-Up section with ** blue links to the source code** on the right hand side. This links don`t show, when I click on React components. When I click on components like for instance Evaluate Script, the blue links on the right hand side show.

Isn`t **source mapping** supposed to work "out-of-the-box" with **create-react-app 16** in **development**.
I want to source-map only in **development** using **Chrome Dev tools**. Source mapping is activated in the Chrome Browser. What am I missing?
Thx in advance

P.S.:Since I haven`t got 10 reputation points I´m not suppose to use screenshots, which in this case made things not quite easy. I hope I managed to explain my problem sufficiently, though.

Comment: Here is a link to a screenshot of the missing links to the source code. In the Timings section I clicked on the React Component called app(blue reactangle to the left), but no links in Button-Up section(blue rectangle to the right). Link:  https://i.imgur.com/AB5kBcE.jpg

Answer (score 3):

The Source Files for Debugging will be available under your **localhost:3000**  in the Chrome devtools.

We always tend to search under **webpack://**
Changes have been made to the newer versions I beleive

[image]

We always tend to search under **webpack://**

Changes have been made to the newer versions I beleive

Answer (score 0):

Could you check the file

node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js

Search there for the sourceMap and sourceMaps, and see if that is ok for you.
You can copy that file like "_original", and then set 
sourceMaps: true,

in all ocurrences. After that, **completely stop** the app, and then start it again.

Is that working now?

To verify which sourceMap is working or not, add the sources to workspaces and check for the green dot:
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/workspaces/